# how to refresh the Label which is inside the Grid view using Java script?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, timer

i am displaying time in the label which is inside the grid view. i need to Refresh the label every second. how to do this by Java script.Like Ajax timer.

EDIT:

`OnLoad="setTimeout(window.location.reload();. 1000);"` whats wrong with this code or `<asp:Label ID="Label2" Width="100px" runat="server" OnLoad="setTimeout(window.location.reload();. 1000);" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="Black" Text='<%# Bind("time") %>'></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
  var now = new Date();
  $('#yourSpanId').text(now.toUTCString()); // or whatever formatting you need
}, 1000);
```

Comment: no i already bind the time using c# code behind..just i need to refresh it so that its look like digital clock..

Comment: You need to refresh your grid then? Are you using UpdatePanels? Some code sample will be useful... - or just Google for 'Ajax timer'

Comment: OnLoad="setTimeout(window.location.reload();. 1000);" whats wrong with this code or           <asp:Label ID="Label2" Width="100px" runat="server" OnLoad="setTimeout(window.location.reload();. 1000);"  Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="Black"
                                    Text='<%# Bind("time") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: There is no point in doing this serverside, its overkill. This is best suited to Javascript, doing something like Jakub suggested.